# youtubeExtractor for Android

Tags: android, youtube, path, extractor

I want to use youtubeExtractor for android app and I found library like

```
compile 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

There is a sample code in github I copied it. After I open app, it closes at the same time. There isn't an error in phone and also Logcat. Only there is 
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/oz.videos-1/lib/arm64 on logcat. I am not sure this is a error or not. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.VideoMeta;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeExtractor;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YtFile;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private static String youtubeLink;

private LinearLayout mainLayout;
private ProgressBar mainProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    mainProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgrBar);

    // Check how it was started and if we can get the youtube link
    if (savedInstanceState == null && Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction())
            && getIntent().getType() != null && "text/plain".equals(getIntent().getType()))
    {

        String ytLink = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        if (ytLink != null
                && (ytLink.contains("://youtu.be/") || ytLink.contains("youtube.com/watch?v=")))
        {
            youtubeLink = ytLink;
            // We have a valid link
            getYoutubeDownloadUrl(youtubeLink);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_no_yt_link, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    } else if (savedInstanceState != null && youtubeLink != null) {
        getYoutubeDownloadUrl(youtubeLink);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

private void getYoutubeDownloadUrl(String youtubeLink)
{
    new YouTubeExtractor(this)
    {

        @Override
        public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
            mainProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (ytFiles == null) {
                // Something went wrong we got no urls. Always check this.
                finish();
                return;
            }
            // Iterate over itags
            for (int i = 0, itag; i < ytFiles.size(); i++) {
                itag = ytFiles.keyAt(i);
                // ytFile represents one file with its url and meta data
                YtFile ytFile = ytFiles.get(itag);

                // Just add videos in a decent format => height -1 = audio
                if (ytFile.getFormat().getHeight() == -1 || ytFile.getFormat().getHeight() >= 360) {
                    addButtonToMainLayout(vMeta.getTitle(), ytFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }.extract(youtubeLink, true, false);
}

private void addButtonToMainLayout(final String videoTitle, final YtFile ytfile)
{
    // Display some buttons and let the user choose the format
    String btnText = (ytfile.getFormat().getHeight() == -1) ? "Audio " +
            ytfile.getFormat().getAudioBitrate() + " kbit/s" :
            ytfile.getFormat().getHeight() + "p";
    btnText += (ytfile.getFormat().isDashContainer()) ? " dash" : "";
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText(btnText);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String filename;
            if (videoTitle.length() > 55) {
                filename = videoTitle.substring(0, 55) + "." + ytfile.getFormat().getExt();
            } else {
                filename = videoTitle + "." + ytfile.getFormat().getExt();
            }
            filename = filename.replaceAll("\\\\|>|<|\"|\\||\\*|\\?|%|:|#|/", "");
            downloadFromUrl(ytfile.getUrl(), videoTitle, filename);
            finish();
        }
    });
    mainLayout.addView(btn);
}

private void downloadFromUrl(String youtubeDlUrl, String downloadTitle, String fileName)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(youtubeDlUrl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle(downloadTitle);

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to implement the version 2.0.0 of the library:
`implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v2.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

May be your `savedInstanceState == null`, and then `finish()` method called. 
Try call `getYoutubeDownloadUrl()` with youtube link after `mainProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgrBar);`